# Import data to existing schema from dmp file

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, datapump

> ```
> ORA-39083: Object type ALTER_PACKAGE_SPEC failed to create with error:
> ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms
> Failing sql is:
>
> ALTER PACKAGE "XZB"."P_IATA"   COMPILE SPECIFICATION     PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL=  2    PLSQL_CODE_TYPE=  INTERPRETED   
> PLSQL_DEBUG=  FALSE    PLSCOPE_SETTINGS=  'IDENTIFIERS:NONE' REUSE
> SETTINGS TIMESTAMP '2015-07-24 05:12:12'
> ```

I get above error when I try to import schema which is already existed.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [documentation of the current database release](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ERRMG/ORA-01500.htm#ERRMG-GUID-65B2B9E5-7075-4D53-91B8-FCAECA0AEE0E)

**Oracle Database Error Messages**
12c Release 2 (12.2)
E49883-13

In the documentation of the current release you will find only

> **ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms**

This is not helpfull (The 11.2 documentation does not contain the message at all). In this case check the 
[documentation of the 9i release](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e1500.htm#1003914).

**Oracle9i Database Error Messages**
Release 2 (9.2)
Part Number A96525-01

It  may contain outdated but nevertheless useful information:

> **ORA-01775 looping chain of synonyms**
>
> **Cause:** Through a series of CREATE synonym statements, a synonym was defined 
>       that referred to itself. For example, the following definitions are circular:
>
> ```
> CREATE SYNONYM s1 for s2 
> CREATE SYNONYM s2 for s3 
> CREATE SYNONYM s3 for s1
> ```
>
> **Action:** Change one synonym definition so that it applies to a base table or view and retry the operation.

So check if the package specification of XZB.P_IATA contains such a synonym.